# Linker Errors due to being Already Defined

Tags: c++, libcurl, linker-errors, msvcrt

It has been about a year since I wrote any .dll plugins that use LibCurl, but I decided to start on another one tonight. Unfortunately, I have been combating the same linker errors for almost 4 hours now, and I am completely lost.

I am statically building LibCurl, and it appears to be fine for the most part, except I am getting the following linker errors.

```
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in memoverride.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in memoverride.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in memoverride.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in memoverride.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: __strdup already defined in memoverride.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : error LNK2005: __malloc_crt already defined in memoverride.obj
```

I have tried...

1) Reorganizing my included libs due to MSDN saying LNK2005 was caused by this.

2) Rebuilding the LibCurl lib through MSVC Application, then through the Command-Line tool.

3) Excluding the libs that are causing issues.

and a bunch of other things that I cannot even remember now. Can anyone help me out with some information as to how I can solve these?

Comment: is memoverride.cpp your file?

Comment: Yeah. And actually after all that time, it looks like the issue is my project being /MT and the libcurl .lib being /MD. Changing my project to /MD or libcurl to /MT though just seems to spew errors.

Comment: Of course after all that time, I read the FAQ and MSDN again and fix it instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was my .dll was /MT while the libcurl was /MD. Also, I had initially blocked "libcmt", so when I was switching libcurl to /MT, it was spewing errors.